# Native PowerShell equivalent of UNIX diff and patch

Tags: unix, powershell

I have a requirement to potentially patch a file on the fly as part of a script.

In order to make what the script is doing more readable I'd like to implement this in a manner similar to the UNIX "diff" and "patch" approach.  On standard UNIX systems diff can generate a specially formatted text file which represents the differences between two files.  This may be consumed by "patch" along with the file to modify in order to generate the changed file in a clean and straightforward way.

It appears that there is no straightforward way to do this in PowerShell.  Options I've seen are to use multiple line regular expressions - which are hard to build and to interpret, consuming the whole file and processing it line by line or encoding the new file that I want to have in the script as a Base64 string and simply decoding it to the target file.

While Compare-Object looks as though it could do something to generate an appropriate diff object there appears to be no easy way to use the output of Compare-Object to apply a change to an array of strings.

Comment: A diff utility is known as `fc`, maybe you can use that one. This also helps of your diffs are binary, this way you call `fc /b` to compare files in question.

Comment: Fc.exe is a useful tip - but it doesn't solve the key issue of then applying the output (a patch) to the original file to create the new file.

Comment: Compare-Object would be the obvious start for this. The best thing you could do it show some sample data files (a few lines) and what the resulting file should look like. Unix is not my strong point but I know I could help if you show some samples.

Comment: You can use `fc.exe` with `/n` switch, this way the difference output would probably be sufficient to build a patch from it. With `/b` mode you already get a verbose output that you can use to build a patch. But there's no straightforward way to make a patch or have a patch command, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

`Compare-Object` is the closest thing to `diff`, and there's no equivalent to `patch` built into PowerShell. If you need that functionality I'd recommend using the Windows ports of [`diff`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) and [`patch`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no native equivalents in `Powershell`.

If you have `Git` installed, you could use `diff` and `patch`:

```bash
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\diff.exe' --help
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\patch.exe' --help
```

```bash
# create file "abc"
@'
a
b
c
'@ | Out-File -Encoding utf8 abc

# create file "axz"
@'
a
x
c
'@ | Out-File -Encoding utf8 axc

# diff both files
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\diff.exe' -u abc axc

    --- abc 2022-07-24 23:58:01.797099100 +0200
    +++ axc 2022-07-24 23:58:01.797099100 +0200
    @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
     a
    -b
    +x
     c

# diff both files and save output to file "patch"
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\diff.exe' -u abc axc | Set-Content patch

# apply patch "patch" to file "abc" and save output to file "patched"
& 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\patch.exe' -su -i patch -o patched abc

Get-Content patched
    a
    x
    c
```